# How can I use PHP code in a webform field?

Tags: entities, webforms

I have to store location information of users, so I have installed the smart IP module, which provides users country information using user's IP. by using this module, I have to use PHP code into some field to print the country information.

but I don't see any field which can support PHP code as default value.

Comment: webform already store the user IP, then may use smart_ip_get_location($ip_address) to use smart ip functionality

Comment: Are you really using the web form module? My guess is that you are dealing with the user registration form?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the reply. I am using Webform module. but I don't know how to store country name using Smart IP module

Comment: I wanted to print country name, so I thought I can use below code, but fields dose not support to add PHP CODE
<?php 
echo $_SESSION['smart_ip']['location']['country'];
?>

Comment: could some one please let me know the code of Smart IP function that can be used in any module by passing IP address?